# memoization function in javascript

Tags: javascript, memoization, nested-function

So I came across a momoize function when I was trying to understand how memoization really works, the solution has really had me thinking, the code below

```js
const memoize = (fn) => {
  const cache = {};
  return (...args) => {
    let cacheKey = args.map(n => n.toString() + '+').join('');
    if (cacheKey in cache) {
      console.log(cache[cacheKey])
      return cache[cacheKey];
    }else {
      let result = args.reduce((acc, curr) => fn(acc, curr), 0);
      cache[cacheKey] = result;
      console.log(result)
      return result;
    }
  }
}
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const memoizeAdd = memoize(add)
memoizeAdd(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

My question is how the momoize variable takes the add function as an argument and memoizeAdd also takes a wide range of argument, If add function only accepts 2 arguments? please, this question comes from a place of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

`add` is passed as the argument to the `memoize` function. If you look closely, you will notice that `fn` (which is referring to `add`) is always called with two arguments only.

This is because the `memoize` function calls the `fn` argument along with `reduce` (which is meant to process an array, even without a defined length).

Effectively, applying `reduce` with a function that just adds two parameters will return the sum of all the elements, which is the expected result of `memoizeAdd`.

I think checking [how reduce works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) might help you

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I issue was the fact the the add function was first pass as an argument, before memoizeAdd took the second argument. Now I full understand, knowing that the add function is used as the callback for the reduce function.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are there.

1. We can pass [function as parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) in JavaScript(and can be executed from there).
2. And what you have been created is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
> with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment).

When you created and assigned memoizeAdd, closure creates its scope for add function. and returns another function that takes many(...args) arguments.

now you called that returned method(memoizeAdd) with arguments.

the variable `chache` will be available for this `add` method scope.

Now if you creates another memoize

```
const mul = (a, b) => a + b;
const memoizeMul = memoize(add)
memoizeMul(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Now it creates another scope and keep cache separate from the `add` version.